# How do I check in this code if the number is in integer?

Tags: c++, int, codeblocks

I wrote this code to check the exceptions I learned in a video, and now I tried to make the cube of an integer and if the entered number is not an integer I want the exception to be announced to the user.

```
#include <iostream>

float cube( float x)
{
    char ch;
    std::cin.get(ch);

    if(ch=='.')
        throw "Should be an integrer";

    float cube=x*x*x;
    return cube;
}

int main ()
{
    float x;
    std::cout<<" Enter an integrer : ";
    std::cin>>x;
    float cube_x=cube(x);
    std::cout<<"Cube("<<x<<")="<<cube_x<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the value from the user as a string.   Check if that strings contains a `'.'` BEFORE calling `cube()`, or attempting to extract a numeric value from it.     If the `'.'` is followed by any digits, then the value is not an integer.   You can also discard rubbish input such as `AC$`.    BTW:  "integer" is spelt with only one 'r'.

Comment: Reading input inside the `cube` function is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boost [lexical-cast](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.lexical_cast) which is exactly for this purpose. It will throw an exception the conversion fails. Boost is well tested and you can safly use it to do the conversion for you.

This could look like this:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int cube(int x)
{
    return x*x*x;
}

int main()
{
    std::string x;
    std::cout << " Enter an integrer : ";
    std::cin >> x;
    try
    {
        int y = boost::lexical_cast<int>(x);
        int cube_x = cube(y);
        std::cout << "Cube(" << x << ")=" << cube_x << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, if your program shall only handle integers, you should also use type `int` and not `float` to handle the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your source code:

```
#include <math.h>       /* round, floor, ceil, trunc */
...

if (x == round(x)) {
   ...
}
```

Explanation can be found here: [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/)